# Find the least positive integer that can be added to the product of any four consecutive integers such the result is always the square of an integer.

Tags: number-theory

Do I need to use some kind of formula or just plug in numbers and find the one that works best?

What I tried doing so far is plugging in random numbers but whenever I multiply the four consecutive integers they always give me a square so adding $2$ makes it a non square root number (i.e.: $1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24 + 2 = 26$. $26$ does not have a square root.).

Comment: Not sure why you were adding $2$ there. In fact, we are not just talking about the *least* positive integer but the *only* integer that can be added to such a product and *always* give a square number.

Comment: @DanielMarksman Please do not vandalize posted (and answered) questions, including your own.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestive hint too long for a comment:

$$
1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 + 1 = 25  = 5^2
$$
$$
2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 + 1 = 121  = 11^2
$$
$$
  3 \times 4 \times 5 \times 6 + 1 = 361  = 19^2
$$

Comment: When you add one shouldn't the integer have to be positive which would make it 12? So 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 + 12 = 36 = 6^2?

Comment: @DanielMarksman I don't understand your comment. $1$ is a positive integer. Yes, you can add $12$ to that product and get a square, but you can't add $12$ to every one of the products and get a square every time.